# Differences between Dates in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a situation where I need to get the differences between two columns.

```
Column 1: 01-OCT-13 10:27:15  
Column 2: 01-OCT-13 10:28:00
```

I need to get the differences between those above two columns. I tried using '-' operator but the output is not in an expected way.
I need output as follows: 00-00-00 00:00:45

I can get it in Oracle using MOD function. But I am not sure about SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drop table #t1

create table #t1(clo1 datetime,col2 datetime)

insert into #t1 values('01-OCT-13 10:27:15','01-OCT-13 10:28:00')

select cast((col2-clo1) as time) from #t1
```

<kbd>[See Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14583)</kbd>

Comment: i was trying exactly same!

Comment: HI Its working good but the resulting columns are bit tedious to understand. I suspect the result. Can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: Hey got it..simple typo..Thanks alot

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DATEDIFF`

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ss,startDate,endDate)
```

## [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ef08/2)

[DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (datepart, Column 1,Column 2)
```

Values for datepart:

```
mi : minute
ss,s: second
```

So,

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (s, Column 1,Column 2)
```

Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) for more